# Modifying the values of parameters in crystal reports

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports, report

I have a stored procedure in sql which I would like to use in crystal reports it has a busId. I have a table called buses. My users don't know the id by heart, but they do know the name of the bus. I would like the user to be able to choose from a list of bus names and the parameter will switch it over into an id. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Add Buses table to the report but don't join it to the SP and don't use it for anything else. 
Create a dynamic parameter with the Buses table as the data source. 
Set BusID as value, and BusName as 'Descripion'.